# drand and drandm in fortran are giving numbers outside of [0,1] range

Tags: random, fortran, gfortran

here is my script below, I use implicit none because I would like to eventually implement them in a bigger program with more variables.

```
program testdrandm
implicit none
real, external :: drand, drandm, rand

        print *, 'drand', drand(0), drand(0)
        print *, 'drandm', drandm(0), drandm(0)
        print *, 'rand', rand(0), rand(0)
end program testdrandm
```

here is my output:

```
 drand  4.3290930E-39  -686.1465
 drandm -8.9381798E+10  1.7946890E+19
 rand  0.9679557      0.1896898
```

The first number is within range but extremely small and will give me zero values when I use it to multiply other values. Rand works but I would like to use drandm. I would like to get random numbers between 0 to 1. Please let me know if I am using this function incorrectly.

Comment: drand (a legacy from 30 years ago when there was no Fortran standard random number generator) would require a type declaration, such as external real(kind(1d0)):: drand. You have told the compiler to take half of the probable 64 bit result and treat it as single preciision.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and see [ask]. Those functions are compiler-specific non-standard extensions. You have to tell us the version of your compiler, show the complete code you compile and show the compiler options you use.

Comment: If you are using Intel Fortran, notice this sentence in the manual *"The intrinsic functions RANDOM_NUMBER and RANDOM_SEED provide the same functionality and they are the recommended functions to use when writing programs to generate random numbers."* https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-drand-drandm Also the manual says, that one should **use the IFPORT module** `use IFPORT`.

Comment: hi, this is the version I have, sorry about that, GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)

Comment: Also, the `external` attribute and the whole `real, external :: drand, drandm, rand` declaration is wrong. Just delete it or replace `external` by `intrinsic` and report back. You should show us your **complete code**. Are there and `drand` and `drandm` procedures within your code? You have to report your complete **compilation command** (`gfortran ...`) including all **libraries** you are linking. See [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

You should use the intrinsic `random_seed` and `random_number` to generate random numbers in Fortran. The intrinsic `random_number` will give you real number(s) between 0 and 1.

See e.g.:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html#RANDOM_005fSEED
- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fNUMBER.html#RANDOM_005fNUMBER

Comment: It's quite legitimate to use other procedures to generate random numbers (perhaps for portability reasons or quality requirements). The question is about specific functions which this answer appears not to address.

Comment: If the original question was about legacy code, I would agree.

The procedures mentioned in the original questions are vendor specific.

The `random_number` procedure has been an intrinsic procedure in the standard since Fortran 90, so should be more portable, (and as mentioned by the other comments, even preferred by the vendor these days).

Answer (score 3):

@tim18 touched on the answer, but you might not have picked up on exactly WHY you got these results.

I modified the program to print the hex representation of the values returned. When run using ifort, I get:

`drand 00000000002F23C0 00000000C42B8960
drandm 00000000D1A67C90 000000005F791029
  rand 000000003F77CBF2 000000003E423E09`

IEEE double precision is an 8-byte format, and drand/drandm return 8 bytes, but you declared them as `real` (single precision), so you get only the low 4 bytes and NOT a conversion. Because the size of the exponent field is different between these types (8 bits vs. 11 bits), interpreting the low 4 bytes of a double as a real will get you wrong values.

Now see what happens if I declare drand and drandm as double precision:

`drand 3EF791E0002F23C0 3FB5C4AFC42B8960
drandm 3FE33E47D1A67C90 3FEC88145F791029
  rand 000000003F77CBF2 000000003E423E09`

or if I go back to list-directed:

```
 drand  2.247793601009899E-005  8.503244914348818E-002
 drandm  0.601352605317418       0.891611277075303
 rand  0.9679557      0.1896898
```

Better?

That said, I wholly agree with those who suggest using `RANDOM_NUMBER` instead. You would not have seen this sort of problem if you used the intrinsic procedure.